# What's the tiniest modification necessary to convert a bilateral, to unilateral, sales contract?

Tags: contract-law, england-and-wales

1. While trying to modify as little as possible, how can I make the bilateral sales contract in Practical Example 1 unilateral?
2. What if I copy and paste Practical Example 2 and modify like it this?

> <s>Daniel</s> [Alex]  offers (or promises) <s>a free watch</s> [a bicycle] to anyone who <s>three tokens from the packets of cereal he manufactures, together with a cheque for £5</s> [pays him £150].

But then doesn't my edit become a bilateral contract?

Poole, Shaw-Mellors. [*Contract Law Concentrate* (4 ed 2019)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Contract-Law-Concentrate-Jill-Pool/dp/0198840446/ref=dp_ob_title_bk). p 5.

> ## The key distinction: bilateral and unilateral agreements
>
> Broadly, agreements will be one of two types:
>   • bilateral
>   • unilateral.
>
> ### Definition
>
> **Bilateral agreements:** by far the most common in practice and consist of a promise in
>   exchange for a promise. Bilateral means both parties are bound on the exchange of promises,
>   although there has yet to be any performance of those promises.
>         A typical sale of goods agreement is bilateral.
>
> #### Practical example 1
>
> Alex offers (or promises) to sell his bicycle to Becky for £150 and Becky accepts, thereby promising
>   to pay £150. (We will use this as our example of a bilateral agreement and look at variations and additions
>   to the facts throughout this chapter.)
>
> ### Definition
>
> **Unilateral agreements:** consist of a promise in exchange for an act. It follows that only one party is
>   bound at the outset by a promise. The other’s acceptance is the performance of the requested act.
>         For example, a typical unilateral agreement will involve an offer of a reward and may be
>   phrased as an ‘if’ contract: I promise to pay £50 to anyone who finds and returns my lost dog.
>
> #### Practical example 2
>
> Daniel offers (or promises) a free watch to anyone who returns three tokens from the packets of
>   cereal he manufactures, together with a cheque for £5. Emily accepts by returning the three tokens
>   with her cheque for £5. (We will use this as our example of a unilateral agreement and return to this
>   example later in the chapter.)

p 6.

> ### Making the correct distinction.
>
> It is not possible to accept a unilateral offer by promising to
>   find and return the lost dog or by promising to collect and return the tokens and the cheque. By
>   comparison, the agreement to sell the bicycle cannot be unilateral. Students sometimes suggest
>   that a simple sale contract is unilateral by interpreting the act of paying for the bicycle as the
>   requested act. This is incorrect since, as long as it is possible to accept by promising to buy (which
>   it is in the example), the agreement will be bilateral.

Comment: Why do you think "Alex offers a bicycle to anyone who pays him £150" is a bilateral contract? Who is the second party that is bound to the terms of this contract?

Answer (score -1):

> how can I make the bilateral sales contract in Practical Example 1 unilateral?

The contract would be unilateral if Practical Example 1 ("*Alex offers (or promises) to sell his bicycle to Becky for £150 and Becky accepts, thereby promising to pay £150*") were modified as follows:

*Alex offers to sell his bicycle to Becky for £150, and Becky pays £150*.

That is because "*[a] unilateral contract is one in which the promisor does not receive a promise in return as consideration*", [*In re Certified Question*, 432 Mich. 438, 446 (1989)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/1989870432mich4381854). In this modification of Practical Example 1, Alex is not receiving a promise. Instead, he is receiving the amount of money he requires for giving the bike away.

> What if I copy and paste Practical Example 2 and modify like it this?
>
> [...]
>
> doesn't my edit become a bilateral contract?

No, the contract remains unilateral. For it to become bilateral, Alex would have to be open to receive a *promise* (whether of payment or of any other sort of consideration) in exchange for the bicycle.

> What's the tiniest modification necessary to convert a bilateral, to unilateral, sales contract?

The modification consists of precluding any *exchange of promises*, and instead requiring the promisor to do good on his promise once a counterparty performs the act(s) the promisor formulated as condition(s) for fulfilling his promise.

Note that the issue of being unilateral or bilateral is mostly pointless for deciding contract disputes. In fact, footnote 10 of *In re Certified Question* reads:

> [D]efinitions of unilateral and bilateral contracts were not included in the Second Restatement of Contracts, because of doubt as to the utility of the distinction.

(quotation marks omitted)

The fact that "*its use by appellate courts has increased*", *Id.*, does not imply that the distinction between unilateral and bilateral contracts is any relevant for ascertaining which party breached a contract and/or the award to which a wronged/injured party would be entitled.

Comment: Thanks Inaki as always! You cited a Supreme Court of Michigan, and I know you've lived in Michigan, but my question involved English law. Do you know of any English cases?

Comment: @Ghreu You're very welcome. Although I am not knowledgeable of English precedents on this, I highly doubt there is any material difference, since the remark from *In re Certified Question* is equivalent to how the topic is covered in the textbook (which in turn seemingly is premised on English law). It is likewise doubtful that under English law an agreement being unilateral versus bilateral would make any difference when it comes to identifying the parties' rights and duties.

Comment: @Ghreu I can provide an example of relevant case law for unilateral contracts: _Carlill v. Carbolic Smoke Ball Co._ [1893] EWCA Civ 1

Comment: "Alex offers to sell his bicycle to Becky for £150, and Becky pays £150." - this is not a unilateral contract because Alex makes his offer to Becky specifically (as opposed to promising the world at large to do something if action X is performed) and Becky can accept the offer prior to completing the act by promising to pay. The act of payment does not convert a bilateral contract into a unilateral one. By this logic, every item purchased in a shop would be a unilateral contract: "I'll give you this apple if you pay me £1" or "I'll pay you £1 if you give me that apple".

Comment: @JBentley "*Becky can accept the offer prior to completing the act by promising to pay.*" You are missing the crucial element that renders a contract *unilateral*. In unilateral contracts the offeree's promise to pay is not a cognizable acceptance (a promise means nothing in unilateral contracts). Absent a cognizable acceptance, there is no formation of contract.

Comment: @IñakiViggers Your version of a unilateral contract is not what is taught in university contract law courses. A contract involving the simple sale of an item for money is bilateral. "A promise means nothing in unilateral contracts" is fine, but only *if* you have a unilateral contract in the first place, which you don't have if you have an agreement between two specified parties.

Comment: "Promising to pay does not count as acceptance in a unilateral contract.". This is circular reasoning. In order for promising to pay to not count, you need a unilateral contract. Once again, you do not have a unilateral contract because Alex's offer to sell the bike is made to Becky. The clue is in the "bi" (which means two) vs "uni" (which means one). In order to to be unilateral the offer from Alex would need to be "I will give my bike to the first person to hand $150 to me". The minute he makes an offer to Becky specifically, she can accept that offer.

Comment: As for the precedent, you are attempting to apply it to a scenario which it did not apply to. I can assure you that the millions of simple sale of goods transactions which happen every day around the world (e.g. every time you buy newspaper in a shop) are standard bilateral contracts. Unilateral contracts are far rarer and contained to specific circumstances. You can refer to the famous Carbolic case for the classic unilateral contract.

Comment: @JBentley "*to be unilateral the offer from Alex would need to be "I will give my bike to the first person to hand $150 to me".*" The premise of Alex making an offer "to the first person who [does X]" rather than specifically to Becky has nothing to do with the contract being *uni*- or *bi*-lateral. [A bilateral contract is a contract in which both parties exchange promises to perform](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/bilateral_contract).

Comment: The very link you have provided gives exactly the example you are trying to use as a unliateral contract, but as a bilateral contract: "the most common types of bilateral contracts are business contracts such as sales contracts for which the buyer promises to pay the price and the seller promises to deliver the goods.". "I'll sell you my bike for £150" is exactly such an offer, which is capable of acceptance by the oferee promising to pay.

Comment: @JBentley "*which is capable of acceptance by the oferee promising to pay.*" In that case, that would be a bilateral contract because a bilateral contract is one where "*the buyer promises to pay the price and the seller promises to deliver the goods*". In the example given in this answer, Becky is not promising to pay. Instead, she is paying upfront. No exchange of *promises* takes place (payment precludes the need for Becky's promise to pay Alex), which is the difference between unilateral and bilateral contracts.